# Logic of using Parent's PE when valuing RemainCo and SpinCo of a spinoff?

Tags: stock-valuation

Reading an older book by Maurece Schiller, there is a section about ways to value companies planning / undergoing a spinoff. In it, **he uses the parent's PE multiple to value the earnings of both the SpinCo and RemainCo**. This is a bit confusing to me, since I would think that it would make more sense to use multiples from businesses whose fundamentals are more closely comparable to the separated businesses (the way I usually see relative valuation done) and the use of the old parent multiple seems a bit arbitrary. From the book...

> For example, if the parent
>   company stock is priced at $60, **based on 12 times earnings** of
>   $5 a share, exclude the subsidiary’s contribution of [assumed in this example to be] $1 a share,
>   and then calculate the price of the stock. This would be 12 times
>   $4, or $48 a share. **The next step is to estimate the value of the
>   subsidiary’s stock based on 12 times earnings**. If we assume the
>   subsidiary earnings of $2.50 a share [the total undistributed earnings of the subsidiary in this example], then the estimated value
>   would be $30 a share. Adding the values of the parent and the
>   subsidiary shares of $48 and $30 respectively, we have an
>   indicated worth of the parent stock of $78 a share as a divestiture
>   situation.

Can someone explain the logic of using the parent's multiple rather than some other comparable business here (assuming such comps exist)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently asked someone with formal finance education about a similar valuation decision they made when analyzing a spinoff situation, and they said something to the effect of...

> I made the decision not to [use multiples from comps as opposed to the parent's valuation ratios] in order to illustrate how **the market, at the time, was implicitly valuing two separate businesses in one basket**. By being lumped together in one entity, my thought was they might still **act** like they trade on the *same* multiple **when they shouldn't**. [As for considering the available comps for these businesses] These facts are taken into consideration in determining the *future*/intrinsic value, where SpinCo is comp'd against some SpinCo-equivalent comp's multiple...

So basically, using the parent's multiple for a relative valuation of the Remain- and Spin-Co encodes an assumption that the market will still view (at the initial time of the spinoff, anyway) the new businesses under the same multiple valuation as the parent (though I still have not found anything explaining Schiller's specific reasoning for doing the same or how this logic would work in the case of a spinoff with a different business than the main business of the parent).